# select says socket is ready to read when it is definitely not (actually is closed already)

Tags: c, network-programming

In my server I check if any socket is ready to read using `select()` to determine it. As a result in main loop `select()` is executed every time it iterates.

To test the server I wrote a simple client that sends only one message and then quits. BTW. I use protocol buffers to send information - message means an object of type class Message in this library.

The test session looks like:

1. `select()`
2. server's socket ready to read
3. `accept()` client's socket
4. read message from client's socket
5. `select()`
6. server's socket not ready to read, client's one ready
7. read message from client's socket

The last step is wrong because client has already closed connection. As a result protobuf library gets `Segmentation fault`. I wonder why FD_ISSET says the socket is ready in step 6 when it is closed. How can I check if a socket is closed?

---

EDIT:

I've found how to check if the socket is open

```
int error = 0;
socklen_t len = sizeof (error);
int retval = getsockopt (socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len );
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the socket *is* "readable" if the remote peer closes it, you need to call `recv` and handle both the case where it returns an error, and the case where it returns 0, which indicates that the peer shut down the connection in an orderly fashion.

Reading the `SO_ERROR` sockopt is not the correct way, as it returns the current pending error (from, eg. a non-blocking `connect`)

Comment: Right - `select()` returns *if a `read()` will not block*, not only when there's data available.

Comment: there is one problem: when I want to read data from client I get information the connection is closed. Yes, it is. However there is data to be read in the socket. I need to know if there is data in the socket not if the connection is open.

Comment: @lord.didger: If there was data, and the connection was closed gracefully, you will get the data prior to the 0 sized read.

Answer (score 1):

The socket used for communication between a client and your server will be flagged as readable (i.e. select() will return) when there is data to read, **or** when there's an EOF to read (i.e. the peer closed the connection).

Just read() when select() returns and your fd is flagged. If read() returns a positive number, you got data. If it returns 0, you got EOF. If it returns -1, you have a problem (unless errno is EAGAIN).